# How to exclude a group based on one element of another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
    Claim   Type
    0       1
    107444  2
    107444  5
    107445  2
    107446  2
```

etc...

as a result of this simple query:

```
    select Claim,[Type] from myTbl
    Group by Claim,[Type]
    order by Claim
```

I want to write a query that completely excludes Claims that have a Type = 5, so the result of this would be:

```
    Claim   Type
    0       1
    107445  2
    107446  2
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Why are you using GROUP BY if you're not using any aggregate?

Comment: Do we assume that you are using SQL Server because you have used SQL Server delimiters around the column names?  You should tag your question with the appropriate database as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with logic in the `where` clause:

```
select Claim, [Type]
from myTbl
where claim not in (select Claim from myTbl where [Type] = 5)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks.  Will mark as answer when I can.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the HAVING clause.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp